# Creating Lines in Bounding Box at specified distance apart?

Tags: qgis, distance, extents

How would I automate creating lines a specified distance apart with a square shaped feature class, oriented East to West?

I'm using QGIS.

I tried searching, however I haven't been able to find something specific to what I'm looking for.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: If you can use PostGIS read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24064/filling-a-polygon-with-lines-using-postgis.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Create Grid` method under Vector Creation Tools in the Processing toolbox. The default option is to create the grid using just lines (instead of polygons), if you only want lines in one direction you could set the other axis spacing to a very large number. I haven't tried this but I expect you'd get one line which would be easy to delete by hand.

Comment: if it wasn't for pesky divide-by-zero errors being thrown, setting the spacing to 0 would be a nice way to get lines in only one axis. Sadly negative numbers don't work either (I thought that might shove the vertical lines to one side to make them easier to remove). Same happens with all three methods I tried..